# pass key to object to update nested property value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I store my state in `input`, within onChange function I do below

```
input[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
```

It worked, it will have

`{"name":"james"}` if I have input tag like this

```
<input name='name' onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue=""/>
```

but what if my initial state of input has nested property?

```
{
    "name": "alice",
    "hobby": {
        "outdoor": "hiking",
        "indoor": "reading"
    }
}
```

If I put the name attr at the input as name='hobby.outdoor' the input state object will be invalid

`{"name":"james", "hobby.outdoor":"something"}`

Comment: "hobby.outdor" is a string that will be set as a prop name. Dot is part of a string and will not be considered as code operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That are many way to achieve what you want. One of them is that you can create another handler for hobbies. So you inputs would be like:

```
<input name='name' onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue=""/>
<input name='outdoor' onChange={this.handleHobbyChange} defaultValue=""/>
```

Then you can update the hobby inside `handleHobbyChange`

```
input.hobby[e.target.name] = event.target.value
```

Another way is that you can parse `hobby.outdoor` by regular expression or `String.prototype.split`, but I won't recommend this way.

If you have many nested inputs to handles, you can make handler as a higher order function (a function create a function). For example:

```
const handle = (inputName) => (e) => {
  input[inputName][e.target.name] = e.target.value // or use setState here
}
```

And use it like

```
<input name='outdoor' onChange={this.handle('hobby')} defaultValue=""/>
```

Comment: imagine u have many input, how many custom handler u have to create?

Comment: @AlexYong I've updated the answer. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `setState` like this one:

```
var state = {
    hobby: {
        outdoor: null
    }
};

function setState(target, value) {
    var parts = target.split('.');
    parts.reduce(function (res, p, i) {
        return i === parts.length - 1 ? (res[p] = value) : res[p];
    }, state);
}

setState('hobby.outdoor', 'smoking')
```

Comment: why need to check the length?

Comment: this is to know when to set the value (as opposed to going further down the prop hierarchy)